# cocos2d modify arrays

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray

I have added sprites to my NSMutable Array now I'd like to get to them; I'm using these methods:

```
- (void)selectSpriteForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
       for (CCSprite *sprite in selectedSpritesArray) {
           if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, touchLocation)) {            
               newSprite = sprite;
               break;
           }
       }
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    [self selectSpriteForTouch:touchLocation];      
    return TRUE;    
}
```

How do I have to do it correctly? Right now I'm not able to acces some sprites that are overlapped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion if you want to access overlapped sprites:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)selectSpriteForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
       NSMutableArray *sprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       for (CCSprite *sprite in selectedSpritesArray) {
           if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, touchLocation)) {            
               [sprites addObject:sprite];
           }
       }

       // dont forget to release this array when you are done with it
       return sprites;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works but not for all my sprites.... still I have two sprites which I'm not able to acces them...

Comment: Could you give me some code how you add your sprites? When you are comparing a touch-location like the code above it should not matter if the are overlapping. I guess the error is somewhere else.